# pandas multi-index from JSON document

Tags: pandas, dataframe

How do I convert this multi-column index json document to pandas dataframe?

```
mylist=[
  {
    "col1": "val1",
    "col2": [
      {
        "col21": "val21"
      },
      {
        "col21": "val22"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

What I have tried:

```
# pip install json-excel-converter[extra]
from json_excel_converter import Converter
from json_excel_converter.xlsx import Writer

import pandas as pd

conv = Converter()
conv.convert(mylist, Writer(file="test.xlsx"))
df = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx", header=list(range(2)))
```

To get this as expected:

```
col1    col2
Unnamed: 0_level_1  col21   col21.1
0   val1    val21   val22
```

But I have 2 questions:

1. Is there any way to avoid creating excel file and directly write to dataframe?
2. Is there any other way to achieve the same results?

Comment: If this is an output of elasticsearch query then there is an official module https://github.com/elastic/eland

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the structure of the JSON when it comes back from `json_excel_converter`

```
df.to_dict(orient="rows")
[{('col1', 'Unnamed: 0_level_1'): 'val1',
  ('col2', 'col21'): 'val21',
  ('col2', 'col21.1'): 'val22'}]
```

So need to produce that format from your input JSON.  I've done this in two ways - old school looping and as a list comprehension.

Plus you need to tell pandas to create a *multiindex* from the tuples in the columns

```
newlist = []
for d in mylist:
    myd = {}
    for k in  list(d.keys()):
        if not isinstance(d[k], list):
            myd = {**myd, (k, ""):d[k]}
        else:
            for x, i in enumerate(d[k]):
                myd = {**myd, (k, f"{list(i)[0]}.{x}"):list(i.values())[0]}
    newlist.append(myd)

newlist = [
    {
        **{(k,""):d[k]
             for k in list(d.keys()) if not isinstance(d[k], list)
          }, 
        **{(k,f"{kk}.{i}"):l[kk] 
             for k in list(d.keys()) if isinstance(d[k], list) 
             for i, l in enumerate(d[k]) 
             for kk in list(l.keys())
          },
    }
    for d in mylist
]
df = pd.DataFrame(newlist)
df.columns= pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.columns)
df
```

**output**

```
 col1    col2        
      col21.0 col21.1
 val1   val21   val22
```